# Invertible function without onto

Tags: functions, terminology

I have come across a situation in differential calculus where my mentor said that a function is invertible if it is one one because we consider range of function as domain of function's inverse. What does it mean?

Comment: I didn't get you cauchy sir

Comment: If necessary, the reverse function can take arbitrary values on the points which are not in the image of the original function. The composition of the two will be the identity on the original set. The reverse function may not have an inverse - that is a separate condition.

Answer (score 1):

When we restrict the codomain to the range of the function, then of course, the term onto can be neglected, and only by checking the one one condition, we can say whether the given function is invertible or not. Onto is only needed to be considered, when the image set i.e. range is not equal to the codomain.

Answer (score 1):

The function $$\exp : \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}, \exp(x) = e^x$$ is one-to-one but not onto because $e^x$ is never negative for real values of $x$. But the function $$\exp^+ : \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}^+, \exp^+(x) = e^x,$$ where $\mathbf{R}^+$ is the set of positive real numbers, is onto.

For all $x \in \mathbf{R}$,

$$ \exp(x) = e^x = \exp^+(x) $$

so $\exp$ and $\exp^+$ are essentially the same function except that they have different codomains. If we use $\mathbf{R}$ as the codomain, we can't get an inverse function $\mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$. But if we use $\mathbf{R}^+$ as the codomain, then we have the inverse function $\log : \mathbf{R}^+ \to \mathbf{R}$.

Comment: Yes I got it. Now my doubt is how we can say a function say f ( not provided specifically) is invertible if given f : R ---> R is one one

Comment: @user356861 If someone says $f : X \to Y$ is invertible (if $f$ is one-to-one), they mean $f : X \to \operatorname{image}(f)$ is invertible.

Comment: Suppose there is a question that a function f is one one defined on R. Is f inverse exists? What should be answer

Comment: @user356861 It depends on what definitions you are using. If $f : X \to Y$ is one-to-one, but not onto, then most people would say that $f$ does not have an inverse **on $\pmb Y$**. But $f$ does have an inverse on $\operatorname{image}(f)$ and if you allow yourself [partial functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function) then $f$ is invertible and its inverse is a partial function. My advice is: whatever you are taught is the right answer, write that down.

Comment: So it means exp+ and exp are same functions and every injective function ¥ on set S is Same as Invertible function ¥° except the fact that ¥ has codomain which is superset of codomain of ¥°

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will clarify the gist of the matter:

Remember that the *domain* of a function is the set of all possible inputs to that function, and the *range* is the set of all possible outputs of that function. A function is called *one-to-one* if for every **output** of the function, there is *only* one **input** to the function having that output (one input for every output, and one output for every input, hence the name *one-to-one*).

The inverse of a function maps the **outputs** of the function to its inputs. Thus it maps things in the *range* to things in the *domain* of the original function, hence the *domain* of the *inverse* is the *range* of the *original* and vice-versa. But remember that all functions (not just the one-to-one functions) must map one input to one output; a function cannot map one input to two or more outputs. Thus for the inverse of a function to itself *be* a function, the original function must be one-to-one because the outputs of the original function are the inputs of the inverse function. Being one-to-one ensures that there aren't two inputs to the original function mapping to the same output.

Comment: Yes I got it but my question is why we are not saying that since f is not onto so f is not invertible ( instead of saying since f is injective so by treating range of function as domain of function' s inverse ,f is Invertible)

Comment: And when we should use this concept of invertibility and when not

Comment: @user356861 A function can be invertible even if it's not onto. Using  Trevor's example, $x \mapsto e^x$ is invertible precisely because it is one-to-one. The range of $x \mapsto e^x$ becomes the domain of $\ln x$ and vice-versa. The difference for non-onto functions is that the *codomain* does not become the domain of the inverse because, for non-onto functions, the range is not equal to the codomain. For example: if you treat $x \mapsto e^x$ as an $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ function (which is not onto), then it's still invertible, but its inverse's domain is not $\mathbb R$, but $\mathbb R^+$